# Magento 2 rest api error for wishlist

Tags: magento2, rest-api, wishlist

Below error appears on api call ,

```
[2020-06-18 07:57:42] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5eeb1e76e4607; Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `wishlist_item` AS `main_table`
```

Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369048/unable-to-create-an-order-via-magento-admin-after-upgrading-to-version-2-4-6 This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable magento Catalog Flat for Category from Admin>Store>Catalog>Catalog>Use Flat Catalog Category make it NO.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your response ,  let me check ,

Comment: its already set to no

Comment: Any luck on this @devmage? I am facing exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

The database  **catalog_category_product_index_store0** table does not create that why you getting error. This table is created when indexing for **Category Product** will run properly . Might be in your system Indexing Category Product is not working.
So, you have to do indexing  again .

Comment: i've done reindexing amit sir , still i am facing this error.

Comment: can you please help me out here to , how do i solve it ?

Comment: i have also added a seperate question & code here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315375/magento-2-wishlist-item-delete-error

Comment: Any thoughts on this ? ?

Comment: Any luck on this @devmage ? I am facing exact same issue

Comment: All indexers are ready still facing the similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here:
Want to get all categories by REST API
Magento 2.4.1

missing table catalog_category_product_index_store0

when I check the database I find a table called catalog_category_product_index_store1

when I call

GET https://dev.puresportsstyles.com/rest/all/V1/categories/

I get the error:
{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5fbbd8e7e2f81"}

In Exception Log:
Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mag2ma1h_shop2.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `cat_index`.`category_id`, count(cat_index.product_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` WHERE (cat_index.category_id in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) GROUP BY `cat_index`.`category_id` {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 1146): Report ID: webapi-5fbbd8e7e2f81; Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mag2ma1h_shop2.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `cat_index`.`category_id`, count(cat_index.product_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` WHERE (cat_index.category_id in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) GROUP BY `cat_index`.`category_id` at /home/mag2ma1h/public_html/shop/magento-2_4_1/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208

how can I change catalog_category_product_index_store1 to catalog_category_product_index_store0

i´m afraid just changing the name in the DB will break the site

many thanks for your help